# Input text width to fill the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have seen there are similar topics, but the solutions they offered did not work for me because I have another div between the textbox and the div that i wanna fill.

http://jsfiddle.net/m4MWD/1/

I would like the "Descrizione" input text to fill all the space to its right: i have tried to set the width to 100%

```
 <input style="width:100%" class="boxout" value="...." readonly="true" />
```

and it filled its parent div.label_e_campo, but not the main div I wanted to fill ( div.dettaglio_ente boxfun )

I was not even able to have the second (the one relative to the "Descrizione" field) div.label_e_campo 's width fill the remaining space in the line, as far as I have read, without setting a width it should automatically fill the parent, but it does not in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Some random hint: always put element type (="text" in your case); the CSS has an unclosed bracket; headers should be separated from the body, especially if you are using float; also check out CSS resets and `box-sizing: border-box;` for a successful living

Comment: The bracket on the CSS was a mistake done while cleaning the code to put it into jsfiddle! What do you mean by "headers should be separated from the bod"y?

Comment: Since your header (buttons etc) has nothing to do with the body (labels and textfields), you should separate them in two containing divs, to be able to format them better and singularly, especially if you are floating elements. It is not mandatory, it's just an hint

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the hint. I'm trying to remake a legacy form with absolute (!!!) positions with a more maintainable layout, I can not move buttons too much in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/m4MWD/3/

The Descrizione will not fill the parent, as you have a float on the parent.  I have added a higher level wrap with the floats on.

```
#wrap1 {
float:left;
width:20%;
}
#wrap2 {
float:left;
width:78%;
margin-left:2%;
}
```

And then added this

```
div.label_e_campo input {
width:100%;
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: It works. I would have preferred to have the label next to the input instead of above hit... I'm obtaining this behaviour  by putting float:left on the label and setting the input width to 70% instead of 100%. My solution does not seem too clean, I hope it works in every common browser.